Does anyone know of a way to tie User Attributes to Product Attributes in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Personalization Studio?
Does anyone know of a way to tie together attributes of a user to the attributes of a product for their recipes in Personalization studio?   We have set customer related attributes on our product catalog that match a user attribute and we want it to not consider all related attribute connections for that product, but only the ones that are specific to that user.
Best way to explain it is to give an example.  Let's say all my products have color attributes (red, blue, green, white) and that many products have these attributes.  Obviously, the system can consider these with a booster and promote red products if you are viewing a red product now.  What I want to do though is set a color preference on the user (for example red) and have the recipe consider that color preference when rendering recommendations for emails, so that the user preference for red triggers the recipe to use that product related attribute to give recommendations of red items.  Anyone know how to tie the user attribute to that related product attribute to do this?
